# Is there an alternative way to upload html without using TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I am comfortable editing HTML (I usually use Notepad++). Is there a way for me to upload HTML to my WP site without using the TinyMCE editor? I don't like how it strips tags or puts in unwanted ones. I do not know how else to modify the content of my page without using the Edit Page function in the Admin.

I know there are some plugin alternatives (like TinyMCE Advanced), but I have not been able to find any information on how to use an external rich-text editor with WordPress.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way other than TinyMCE. In my experience it does a good job of handling HTML. TinyMCE advanced will give you more control, should you require it.

Comment: Most of the sanitizing happens in the WordPress code and not while editing in TinyMCE.  This means that the behavior can be changed with plug-ins.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress does a handful of HTML clean-up tasks when you submit your post.  Here are a few:

- "Texturize" the special characters
- Automatic paragraphs - for carriage returns
- Emoticons
- Special characters (like "&" and "<")
- Removing script tags and other "unsafe" stuff

You will want to investigate the [Raw HTML plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/) which has some great provisions for putting some or all raw HTML in your pages and posts.

There is an alternative way to disable the HTML filters - by adding a privilege to your users called "unfiltered_html".  In this way you can allow for unfiltered HTML by user role.  There are also some excellent plug-ins to add this to any roles you'd like - [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/).